# "invalid domain" creating a Master-Detail field on a junction object

Tags: custom-field, master-detail, person-accounts

I was attempting to set up a [Junction Object](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_manytomany.htm&language=en_US) in an organization with [Person Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=account_person.htm&language=en_US) enabled to link Business Accounts with Person Accounts. I set up the Account Master-Detail on the custom junction object, but when I went to add the second Master-Detail I noticed that I couldn't select Account, but "Person" was available.

[image]

Assuming this meant Person Accounts (the child relationship name it provides is "Contacts", but Contacts was a separate option in the dropdown), I went ahead with this. Unfortunately, I received the following error on the final step for saving that I haven't had much luck searching for on Google. Any ideas?

> Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)
>
> There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the
>   affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was
>   "invalid domain".

Comment: Is this the same issue? https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hRUJAA2